# Why is this select2 element selected by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

For some reason, this select2 element on my page is always selected. Here is the most minimal version:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#animals').select2({
            'multiple': true,
        });

        $('#business_types').select2({
            'multiple': true,
        });
    });
```

```
        <div class="mt-2">
            {{ \Form::tLabel('', __('Animals'))}}
            <select name="animals[]" id="animals">
                @foreach($animals as $animal)
                    <option @if(in_array($animal->id, request()->animals ?? [])) selected @endif value="{{ $animal->id }}">{{ $animal->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2">
            {{ \Form::tLabel('', __('Business types'))}}
            <select name="business_types[]" id="business_types">
                @foreach($business_types as $business_type)
                    <option @if(in_array($business_type->id, request()->business_types ?? [])) selected @endif value="{{ $business_type->id }}">{{ $business_type->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
```

This PHP produces this:

```
<select name="business_types" id="business_types" data-select2-id="select2-data-business_types" multiple="" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="1" data-select2-id="select2-data-5-kfne">Alimentation</option>
<option value="2">Animaleries</option>
...
</select>
```

I didn't include the animal select, but it's the same issue: the first element is selected.

I tried removing the PHP and it doesn't help much...

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Add one empty option `<option value=""></option>`before foreachs, inside selects elements.

Comment: @Benilson It doesn't fix the issue, now it's just the empty element which is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to set the "multiple" value on the select to fix this issue.

```
            <select name="business_types[]" id="business_types" multiple="multiple">
                @foreach($business_types as $business_type)
                    <option @if(in_array($business_type->id, request()->business_types ?? [])) selected @endif value="{{ $business_type->id }}">{{ $business_type->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```